# Stackoverflow recursion error when I implement my code to unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, recursion

Ok, so i want the user to specify the width and height of a board/matrix, and then set random spots/coordinates as "bombs" (**the random coordinates have an *x between 0 and the amount of numbers on a row*, and a *y between 0 and the amount of numbers in a column***), I use a list to see if the coordinates have already been marked as bombs, if ***NOT***, mark the spot as bomb and add the coordinates to the list,
if ***YES***, recursion happens until the coordinates havent been used before. Then I check for every item in the matrix, if its a normal spot (0), i print "normal", if its a bomb spot (1), i print "bomb".

The code works **fine** when I **dont run it in unity**, but when i do i get a stackoverflow error

***CODE THAT WORKS WHEN RUN ALONE:***

THIS FILE IS Board.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class Board
{
    byte rows;
    byte columns;
    byte bombsAmount;
    public byte[,] matrix;

    // MEMOIZATION
    List<byte[]> bombPositions = new List<byte[]>();


    public Board(byte rows, byte columns, byte bombsAmount)
    {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.columns = columns;
        this.bombsAmount = bombsAmount;

        MakeMatrix();

        for (int i = 0; i < bombsAmount; i++)
        {
            SetBombs();   
        }
    }

    // makes a matrix with the specified width and height
    public byte[,] MakeMatrix()
    {
        matrix = new byte[rows, columns]; // makes 2d array

        return matrix;
    }

    // gets a random number between 0 and last index of rows
    // gets a random number between 0 and last index of columns
    // checks if random pair of nums has already been used
    // if so, check again
    // if not, set coordinates to bomb and mark it as used
    public byte[,] SetBombs()
    {
        Random RNG = new Random();
        byte xPos = (byte)RNG.Next(0, rows); // the length of a row is the number of columns
        byte yPos = (byte)RNG.Next(0, columns); // the length of a column is the number of rows

        byte[] coords = new byte[] { xPos, yPos };
        bool isOccupied = false;

        try{   
            foreach (var position in bombPositions)
            {
                if (position[0] == coords[0] && position[1] == coords[1])
                {
                    isOccupied = true;
                }
            }

            // BASE CASE
            if (isOccupied == false)
            {
                matrix[coords[0], coords[1]] += 1;
                bombPositions.Add(coords);
            }
            // RECURSIVE CASE
            else
            {
                SetBombs();
            }

        } catch (NullReferenceException)
        {

        } 

        return matrix;
    }
}
```

THIS FILE IS Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Name
{
    class Program{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Board gameboard = new Board(5, 6, 4);
        foreach (var row in gameboard.matrix)
        {
            switch (row)
            {
                case 0:
                    Console.WriteLine("normal");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("bomb");
                    break;
            }
        }
        
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

***CODE THAT DOESNT WORK IN UNITY:***

*they use the same Board.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


class Program : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("normal");
        Board gameboard = new Board(5, 6, 4);
        foreach (var row in gameboard.matrix)
        {
            switch (row)
            {
                case 0:
                    Debug.Log("normal");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Debug.Log("bomb");
                    break;
            }
        }
        
            Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using your recursive [monte carlo method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method), keep a list of all unoccupied locations then every time you place a bomb you select a random item in that list, place the bomb at that location, then remove that item from the list.

Comment: Calling the parameterless `Random()` constructor every time you need a coordinate is also a cause for concern.  "[If [this example\] is run on .NET Framework, because the first two Random objects are created in close succession, they are instantiated using identical seed values based on the system clock and, therefore, they produce an identical sequence of random numbers.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Random__ctor).  So your algorithm will likely be trying only 3 or 4 different coordinates even if `SetBombs` is called hundreds of times.

Comment: Also this `Console.ReadLine();` should not be in a Unity project at all ^^ .. and also really do **NOT** do this `catch (NullReferenceException) { }`!! Rather fix your exception or prevent it but this just makes your debugging impossible! The result may just be -> You call something => Nothing happens at all ... why? The `catch` knows ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ruzihm already said: Do not recursive here at all!
Rather have a list that keeps track of already used positions.

To make things easy (since you are in Unity anyway) I would suggest to use `int` instead of `byte` and instead of your `byte[2]` rather use [`Vector2Int`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2Int.html) which already provides in particular equality comparisons!

For the random I would use Unity built-in [`Random.Range(int,int)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html)

```
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

public class Board
{
    private int rows;
    private int columns;
    private int bombsAmount;

    public int[,] matrix;

    // Unity already provides the wonderful type Vector2Int
    // which implements equality comparisons so we can simply use
    private readonly HashSet<Vector2Int> bombPositions = new HashSet<Vector2Int>();

    // Readonly access
    public HashSet<Vector2Int> BombPositions => new Hashset(bombPositions );

    public Board(int rows, int columns, int bombsAmount)
    {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.columns = columns;
        this.bombsAmount = bombsAmount;

        ResetMatrix();

        SetBombs();
    }

    private Vector2Int GetNextFreeRandomPosition()
    {
        Vector2Int randomPosition;

        // optional emergency break ;)
        var iterations = 0;

        do
        {
            randomPosition = new Vector2Int(Random.Range(0, columns), Random.Range(0, rows));
           
            iterations++;
            if(iterations > rows * columns * 10)
            {
                Debug.LogError("In my opinion I tried it now a reasonable amount of times but couldn't find an unused position ^^");
                return Vector2Int(-1,-1);
            }

        } while (bombPositions.Contains(randomPosition));

        return randomPosition;
    }

    private void ResetMatrix()
    {
        bombPositions.Clear();
        matrix = new int[columns,rows];
    }

    private void SetBombs()
    {
        if(bombAmount > rows * columns)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Impossible to place {bombAmount} on a {rows}x{columns} board!");
            return null;
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < bombAmount; i++)
        {
            var randomPos = GetNextFreeRandomPosition(alreadyUsedPositions);
            bombPositions.Add(randomPos);

            matrix[randomPos.x, randomPos.y] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

and then you MonoBehaviour should look like this if you want it to work correctly

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Program : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        var gameboard = new Board(5, 6, 4);
     
        for(var y = 0; y < 5; y++)
        {
            for(var x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                var field = gameboard.matrix[x, y];
                switch (field)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Debug.Log("normal");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Debug.Log($"bomb at {x},{y}");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on Smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*